# Download a file from dropbox

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a guide or video on how to download a file from my dropbox account by pressing a button in c#. I'd like to store little files that a user could download via my dropbox account.

My program is just a windows form application program.

thanks !

Comment: So basicly you want files from your puvlic folder downloaded? Or do you want to have acces to private folders?

Comment: @Frederiek public would work fine.

Comment: you could have a xml in your public folder that have all the other urls from the files in your dropbox. Then on startup you download that xml file and you could link all the correct urls to your buttons. http://www.csharp-examples.net/download-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [REST API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api) is a good place for you to start reading. There are also some [third party development kits](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk) for .NET which wrap this API into a reusable client library.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the dropbox API at https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start. It provides enough information and examples to get you started !

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox website provides a sample console application .NET code for downloading and doing other stuff. Check out https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial .
In your case you can bind the action of onClick of a button to do the downloading function.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: There is already two answers here already linking to the documentation, including the accepted answer. Unless you want to provide a better answer, by for instance showing some code, then there is no point in posting new answers to such an old question that essentially say the same as existing and accepted answers.